# Google Places Autocomplete + Angular 2 suggestions are not showing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps

I'm using Google places autocomplete via AGM library.

Here is input in my component HTML for search.

```
 <form #addressForm="ngForm" novalidate name="AddressForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Line1">{{ "AddressLine1" | localize }} *</label>
        <input
            id="Line1"
            class="form-control"
            required
            #search
            #line1Input="ngModel"
            type="text"
            placeholder = "{{'Line1Placeholder'| localize}}"
            name="Line1"
            [(ngModel)]="address.line1"
            maxlength="128"
            (change)="checkValidity()"
        />
        <validation-messages [formCtrl]="line1Input"></validation-messages>
</form>
```

Here is my component ts code

```
    export class EditMainAddressComponent extends AppComponentBase
    implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterContentChecked, OnInit {
    @ViewChild('addressForm') addressForm;
    @ViewChild('search') public searchElement: ElementRef;
    required: string | boolean;

    private changed = [];
    private touched = [];

    disabled: boolean;
    address: AddressDto = new AddressDto();
    addressTypes: SelectItem[] = [];
    lat: any;
    lng: any;

    constructor(injector: Injector, private mapsApiLoader: MapsAPILoader, private ngZone: NgZone) {
        super(injector);
        this.addressTypes.push({ label: this.l('Address.Main'), value: AddressType.Main });
        this.addressTypes.push({ label: this.l('Address.Billing'), value: AddressType.Billing });
        this.addressTypes.push({ label: this.l('Address.Delivery'), value: AddressType.Delivery });
        this.addressTypes.push({ label: this.l('Address.Correspondence'), value: AddressType.Correspondence });
    }

    ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
        this.checkValidity();
    }

    checkValidity(): void {}

    get value(): AddressDto {
        return this.address;
    }

    set value(value: AddressDto) {
        if (this.address !== value) {
            this.address = value;
            this.address.latitude = this.lat;
            this.address.longitude = this.lng;
            this.changed.forEach(f => f(value));
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.changed.push(fn);
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.touched.push(fn);
    }

    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }

    writeValue(obj: AddressDto): void {
        if (obj) {
            this.address = obj;
            this.checkValidity();
        }
    }

    validate(): ValidationErrors {
        if (!this.addressForm.valid) {
            return { message: 'custom error' };
        }
        return null;
    }

    registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
        this.checkValidity = fn;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.mapsApiLoader.load().then(() => {
            const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                this.searchElement.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement,
                {
                    types: ['address'],
                }
            );
            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

                    if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

My problem, that I receive places but I don't see a dropdown.

I have response in source tab

> [
>         [
>           "Kings Highway, Brooklyn, NY, USA",
>           null,
>           ["route", "geocode"],
>           "EiBLaW5ncyBIaWdod2F5LCBCcm9va2x5biwgTlksIFVTQSIuKiwKFAoSCZuweFtLW8KJEchDl-1agp_wEhQKEgkJIXyUFkTCiRGGeAAEdFx2gg",
>           "11327283b8eb9070c49203e08cad1a2c4ebe4fe1",
>           [["Kings Highway", 0], ["Brooklyn", 15], ["NY", 25], ["USA", 29]],
>           [[0, 1]],
>           null,
>           "EiBLaW5ncyBIaWdod2F5LCBCcm9va2x5biwgTlksIFVTQSIuKiwKFAoSCZuweFtLW8KJEchDl-1agp_wEhQKEgkJIXyUFkTCiRGGeAAEdFx2gg",
>           ["Kings Highway", "Brooklyn, NY, USA", [[0, 1]]]
>         ],

Where can be a problem?

Comment: Please add working example

Comment: I cannot add working example because of google api key. I added all needed code @Piyush

Answer (score 1):

So propositions modal have `.pac-container` style, that has `z-index` less than modal `z-index`. Setting `z-index` to 99999999 for example helps